# Verifying a transaction root by hand

Tags: transactions, protocol, merkle-patricia-tries

Suppose I have a very simple block with one transaction whose hash is:

```
0xce70a6b3ae683183e9c4d7c5a22ed5e2cf1f82a38fa67acaa24124b42b258b4a
```

And when I run `eth.getBlock` I get the following transaction root:

```
0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421
```

Assuming I have the `keccak256` function, how would I verify this root is correct? I.e. how do I build and encode the transactions trie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to rebuild the trie. It uses the same patricia trie format as seen throughout Ethereum. The best [example is in the wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Patricia-Tree#example-trie)

Items in the patricia trie come in path->value pairs, and for the transaction trie specifically the path is `rlp(transactionIndex)`. `transactionIndex`being its index within the block it's mined (the ordering  decided by a miner). The value is the raw signed transaction.

My js library has functions for both [generating the proof and verifying it](https://github.com/zmitton/eth-proof/blob/master/test/default/transaction.js#L8-L12). It uses the merkle-patricia-tree node module to build the trie.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Patricia-Tree#transactions-trie you should `rlpEncode(transactionIndex)`. So my guess is you'd need to see if that tx hash was present in any of the indexes of the TX trie.

Maybe take a peek at Zac Mitton's https://github.com/zmitton/eth-proof. More specifically https://github.com/zmitton/eth-proof/blob/master/buildProof.js#L147

Answer (score 0):

I created a project to visualize the Ethereum Transaction Merkle Tree data structure using Next.js and react-d3-tree. This might help to understand how to construct the transaction trie and compute the transaction root for the block. The project fetches the block data using web3.js APIs and creates the ethereum transaction trie using the transactions data in the block. Then it walks through the trie data structure to create a json database of nodes. Finally it renders the trie nodes and node details using React components.

Demo:
https://milindmovasha.github.io/show-merkle-tree/

Source Code:
https://github.com/milindmovasha/show-merkle-tree

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in other answers, you would need to build your own **Merkle Patricia Trie**. This can be achieved by `merkle-patricia-tree` node module.

Following implementation works for me:

```js
const RLP = require('rlp');
const { arrToBufArr } = require('ethereumjs-util');
const Trie = require('merkle-patricia-tree').BaseTrie;
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3("http://127.0.0.1:7545");

function createRLPTransaction (transaction) {
    return arrToBufArr(RLP.encode([
        transaction.nonce,
        Number(transaction.gasPrice),
        transaction.gas,
        transaction.to,
        Number(transaction.value),
        transaction.input,
        transaction.v,
        transaction.r,
        transaction.s,
    ]));
};

// Calculates transaction root of a block which contains given transaction
async function calculateTransactionRoot(txHash) {
  const tx = await web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash);
  const block = await web3.eth.getBlock(tx.blockNumber);
  const trie = new Trie();
  const txns = block.transactions;
  for(let i=0; i<txns.length; i++) {
    const currTxn = await web3.eth.getTransaction(txns[i]);
    const rlpEncodedTxn = createRLPTransaction(currTxn);
    const txReceipt = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txns[i]);
    const path = Buffer.from((RLP.encode(txReceipt.transactionIndex)));
    await trie.put(path, rlpEncodedTxn);
  }
  const evaluatedTxnRoot = "0x" + trie.root.toString('hex');
  return evaluatedTxnRoot;
}
```